# I think some users are gaming / abusing a review queue -- what should I do?

Tags: support, help-improvement

I've seen several times where questions have been in the H&I queue and trivial edits have been made by users who have high score in that queue, when much greater improvement could (and should) have been made.

Should I:

1. Mind my own damn business.
2. Bring specifics to meta (at risk of upsetting the user who is more senior on the site than me).
3. Try and get a mods attention (what would they even do? would they care?)

If it was a single occurrence then I'd pass it off as a single bad edit from someone who is tired -- but I'm seeing this a lot from a single user and can't really assume good faith anymore.

Comment: Have you tried to (politely) bring that issue to the attention of the user (in a comment, for instance)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Since there's no way to communicate in private, wouldn't that have the same risks as `2.`?

Comment: Can I assume the person who downvoted supports option 1? @Fred: I have not.

Comment: @Mast, depends on the way it's formulated. An inquiry like *I noticed there were still improvements to be made after some of your edits in the H&I queue, have you considered taking a little more time to assess the whole spectrum of possible requirements* may be taken positively (I'm assuming good faith on both sides here).

Comment: @Fred I will try that. Thank you. I'm sorry that you have reason to doubt my intentions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Also if the comment is made on an old and little-viewed post, and says "let me know when you've seen this so I can remove it" it should not receive much attention from anyone else.

Comment: @TZHX why do you think your intentions are doubted when they are explicitly not?

Comment: I don't think there's ever a realistic way to set an objective standard for a "good enough" edit.  It was tried it the suggested edit review queue and it did not work at all.  If somebody is half-assing it just to get a sliver of HTML added to their profile, well, I hope they still feel good about it when they get it knowing full well that it wasn't exactly "earned".

Comment: @Hans My understanding was that H&I should be used to make substantial improvements to a post -- just changing the capitalisation of "I" or other trivial changes and leaving the rest of the Q a clear mess doesn't meet that goal. It's fine to make the edit -- but subsequently removing the Q from the queue deprives it of the help it was meant to have and -- effectively -- wastes the time of the people who assessed that it need improvement. I don't really care if someone has magic unicorn points they didn't "earn" -- that's not my concern with this.

Comment: Meh, it is only the editor's free time that wasn't used effectively.  Less people will look at the H&I entry.  If he doesn't have enough rep and his edits are being reviewed in the Suggested Edits queue then it is up to the reviewers of that queue to reject it and help him learn to get better at it.  If that deprives a user of substantial H&I help, well, he shouldn't have posted a question that needs that much work.

Comment: @TZHX If you leave/skip questions that were pushed into the queue where **only** minor changes can be made, and skip that question, someone else will get it on their desk and waste reading time for every next reviewer that skips. This is difficult to prevent unless the triage queue concept is changed (and this minor edits can be easily done there: but that would no longer be triaging) But I agree there should not be clear things left if the i->I changes were made.

Comment: @Anthon That is true. But when there *are* other changes to be made, that *can* be made, and you remove it from the queue I believe that goes against the spirit of the queue. You edited my response in as I was typing.

Comment: @TZHX I agree, I also point that out in my answer (last paragraph but one) as something you could comment about.

Comment: @TZHX To underpin my suggestion that we all have different focus (and not in order to be nasty): I was wondering how you would know what the 20 reviewers listed had reviewed, as you (nor I) have the reputation on [so] to see what others reviewed in the H&I review history. So I looked up [your review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/519348/tzhx?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1) and noticed you reject quite a few suggested edits. On the other hand, of the last 11 SE reviews where you approved one was further edited by another reviewer and I was able to improve half of the others.

Comment: @Anthon I agree -- we all have different focuses on the site and when making edits. I approve *suggested edits* when I think they make *improvements* to the post. I skip **a lot** in of the reviews presented to me in all queues I do. I don't enter the suggested edit queue with the intention of fixing **everything wrong with a post**, but judging whether the suggested edits make an improvement. If I have time, I will **improve** or for particularly "bad" suggestions **reject and edit** -- but that is a different queue with a different focus (in my understanding) and thus different expectations.

Comment: @Anthon And... I didn't think "I wonder what people in the H&I queue do" and go look at their reviews, I noticed particular users regularly making what I consider insignificant revisions to posts and then recognised the name when looking at the queue. I'm not trying to start a witch hunt, or a pissing contest.

Comment: @TZHX I don't think you are instigating a witch hunt. and I upvoted your question here. I know one sometimes notices (as I described I did in my posts). It can be a real problem, and I honestly hope I was not one of the people you noticed. But if you did I rather would  know what you think I should improve upon. Not that I have to agree with you, but if I structurally miss things that after being pointed out I will be able to also notice, I would be grateful (ok maybe only after being grumpy for a few minutes)

Comment: Yours is what I would call a meta concern about improvement. And since the system doesn't let me (or you) easily know about which of my changes were further improved upon, improvement of the improvement process itself is cumbersome to say the least. And not having a way to directly address someone (although IMO correct) doesn't help to improve that situation. Pinging the mods is usually not warranted in my experience.

Comment: @Bill Sorry I missed your comment earlier. I was in an odd mood before lunch and somehow misinterpreted what Fred had said. Sorry.

Comment: @TZHX As far as "seniority" goes, that belongs to moderators. High reputation users make mistakes just like low reputation users. Even moderators are held accountable to the community. So don't feel bad if you think a high rep user is doing something wrong/bad.

Comment: I think, "Mind my own business" sounds more established.

Answer (score 22):

As I am one of the high "score" holders in the H&I queue I hope that you are not referring to me specifically.

I have reviewed posts that were already edited by others active **in that queue** (edits probably made outside of the queue) and found things to improve. As always *different people have different focus in changing things*.

If you want to ping some other reviewer, I would first further improve multiple post that such person already improved  (at least 5, probably 10), so you have some concrete "evidence" you can point to, to show you could make further improvements. Then ask if the person would consider taking such changes into account in their edits as well. Apart from backup material, this forces you not to just start out on a hunch.

IMO, you should also review the posts of your suspect.  Check if *their posts* can be further refined with many edits similar to the ones the made in the H&I queue.  If in H&I they *forgot to remove "Thanks"* in questions, or fail to  improve spelling mistakes in such questions, check if that same person made the same mistakes in some of their own posted questions. If they do it is an indication it is something they do not care about.

Instead of commenting, I edited the "thanks" out of the post I found with this approach. The person will be notified by the system that a change was made to one of their own posts. There is no guarantee that the person will see that change, but I consider this a gentler approach (assuming such posts can be found) than direct confrontation.

If you decide to ping a person in a comment, and specify additional edits they missed as part of a review queue edit, you can also point out that it sometimes might be better to skip an question to leave in the queue for someone willing to take the time for a more thorough review. Please word this comment carefully.

And if I happen to be that reviewer or one of the reviewers you were referring to: ***spare me no courtesies*** and tell me how you see it ;-).

Comment: @Anthon "give it to me unadorned" sounds pretty close to "bring it on" in denotative meaning, but TylerH is correct that "bring it on" does carry a somewhat adversarial connotation. It's sort of like a confrontational challenge. Actually, this would probably make a good question for [ell.se]. Feel free to post a question there if you're curious.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I know the term only from the song by Seal from 1994 that I referred to in my comment.  The catch phrase from the refrain being [Bring it on, don't wait until tomorrow](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/seal/bringiton.html). There seem to be multiple connotations.

Comment: @Anthon Yeah, I can imagine that it would be hard to pick up on connotations like that just from song lyrics.

Comment: I believe the usual idiom for that is ["don't mince words"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mince+words).

Comment: @BenVoigt Doesn't "Don't beat around the bush" also work?

Comment: @Aify: I suspect that's intended here as well, but it doesn't mean quite the same thing -- "Don't beat around the bush" refers to getting straight to the point, without unrelated pleasantries.  "Don't mince words" refers to making the point in a direct and possibly abrasive fashion, not softening the message (which might risk misunderstanding).

Answer (score -2):

Ask a question in a comment field.

You are almost never doing harm by asking. If there was a misunderstanding, your question is the opportunity to clarify. If you can learn something, your question is the opportunity to do so.